# is my logic incorrect for adding two integral numbers complying to IEEE-754 standard?

Tags: c, addition, ieee-754

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 32

int binary(int x);
```

I have a structure of 32 bits inside a union
    (1 for the sign, 8 for the exponent and 23 for the mantissa).

```
union{

    int result;

    struct value {
        unsigned int mantissa: 23;
        unsigned int exponent: 8;
        unsigned int sign: 1;
    }fps;
}k;

int p[2] = {0};

int main(void)
{
    int x = 2;
    int y = 2;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    i = binary(x);      
    j = binary(y);
    printf("%d %d",i, j);       

    if(i >= j)
        k.fps.exponent = 127 + i;   
    else
        k.fps.exponent = 127 + j;

    k.fps.mantissa = abs(p[0]-p[1]);

    printf("%d",k.result);

    return 0;   
}
```

I then convert one integer at a time in binary and use a loop (until the number is less than 0) to continuously divide the number by 2 and store the remainder into an array.

```
int binary (int x)
{   
    int total = 0;
    int i = 0;  
    int j = 0;
    int fractional = 0x400000;
    static int z = 0;
    int a[N] = {0};
```

A counter is used to count the number of times the number is divided by two as i will use this to add to the bias(127) in order to obtain the exponent for the result.

```
    while(x > 0){
        a[i++] = x % 2;
        x /=2;
    }
```

I then reverse the array and check if a one occurs and if so I calculate the mantissa.

```
    for(j = i- 2; j >= 0; j--){
        if(a[j] == 1){
            total += fractional;
        }
        fractional /= 2;
    }   

    p[z++] = total;

    return i;
}
```

Comment: You have to equalise the exponents before adding the significands, and then renormalise the sum. It is not immediately obvious whether you are converting two integers to floating point, adding two floating point values " by hand", or both. Also `printf("%d",k.result);` perhaps isn't as useful as using `unsigned result` and then `%08X`.

Comment: 1) `a[i++] = x % 2;` returns `-1, 0, 1`.  Later `if(a[j] == 1){` is not handling -1. 2) No indication of handling sub-normals, infinity, NaN, -0.0.  3)Packing of `union` not guaranteed.  4) `int` may not be 32-bit.  5) No overflow handling.